# how to change the INT_MAX in caffe

Tags: caffe

Recently,I **test** a trained model using my own data. However,my data is large which will exceeds the INT_MAX in caffe. I test only one image at a time.So there is no problem of batch_size.

I am not very familiar with the source code of caffe now.I am wondering if I can change the INT_MAX without change the network. And I would like to know which one determines the INT_MAX.

This is the exceeding INT_MAX error.

```
Check failed: shape[i] <= 2147483647 / count_ (31 vs. 20) blob size exceeds INT_MAX
```

Comment: This is limited by the caffe, which is 2G pixel number.